# Getting list of all custom post type posts and regular posts from a certain category

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of *all* posts from a custom post type called social, *and* any normal posts within the category social. I currently am using the following:

```
$posts = get_posts(
  array(
    'post_type' => array('social', 'post'),
    'category_name' => 'social',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  )
);
```

This seems to only be returning posts within the social category, not the social post type. Anyway to return both post_types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated query expects all the conditions to be true: `post_type`to be either `social` or `post` AND `category_name` to be `social` AND `post_status` to be `publish`.

One simple solution is to use `WP_Query` instead:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('social', 'post'),
    'category_name' => 'social',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
$posts = $query->posts;
```

Then, you may use a `posts_where` filter to modify the `where` part of the query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function my_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    ...modify $where...
    return $where;
}
```

I'll skip the string manipulation part, because there is nothing specific there. Anyhow, `$where` will look something like this (tested with my WordPress installation):

```
"AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (<number>))
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('social', 'post') AND 
((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))"
```

You need to convert it to something like this:

```
"AND ( ((wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (<number>)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post') OR (wp_posts.post_type = 'social'))
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))"
```

Finally, you need to make sure that `my_posts_where` does not break the other queries. I might just add some indicator to the `$query` object to identify this particular query in the filter.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks!